# Does IsNull() guard against references to null objects?

Tags: powerbuilder

In my PowerBuilder application, the following code segment causes an R0002 error at runtime (a null object is being referenced):

```
Window w = windows[idx]
IF NOT IsNull( w ) THEN
    MessageBox( "", "ClassName is " + w.GetClassName() ) // This line crashes
END IF
```

Does anybody know why that is? I was under the impression that IsNull() is specifically meant to test for null values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think these are different kinds of NULL. 
One is a variable with the value of NULL
The other is an object that doesn't exist or hasn't been instantiated.

In the second case, you may want to use isValid().

Answer (score 3):

Use `IsValid(w)` in order to determine whether an object variable is instantiated —- whether its value is a valid object handle.